# AngularJS scoped rails query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I just started learning AngularJS integrated with a Rails backend. I'm confused about where scoped query logic belongs.

I have simple blog with a list of posts and two links which should sort the posts by "newest" and "most voted".

With angular, where is this scope logic? I see there is a 'filter' option on ng-repeat, but it seems inefficient to query `Post.all` in my index action if there are thousands of posts and then use filter to show the top 10 most voted?

I'd appreciate a simple explanation of what should take place from the point of a user clicking the "most voted" link" to interacting with the back-end API to properly scope the query.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a param `order_by` in the request to `PostsController`. Using this param you can decide how to order posts fetched from the database and the send then back to angular.

It's worth noting two things:

1. Don't use `Post.all` because it's inefficient to fetch all the records to the application and even worse to send all of them to the client. Use pagination: fetch a certain number of posts. You can add pagination easily using gems like [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) or [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate)
2. Remember not to put `params[:order_by]` value directly as a  `Post.order()` argument, because it might cause SQL injection. It's mentioned in [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns?view=asciicast)